# Not able to connect with mysql on linux(Cent OS) server

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, centos

I am trying to connect mysql in my node js application. It's working fine into my local but when I tried to deploy application onto live server, I am not able to connect with the mysql.

My mysql credentials are correct, I tried by using below command:

> **mysql -u username -p**

I also tried below command:

> **service restart mysql**

But this command giving me error which is: "**service will not execute and completion _service exists.**"

Don't know what's getting wrong. It's a fresh server which I bought yesterday. You can see the attached error [image: here]

Can anyone please help with the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Error says that the DB is not accessible at `127.0.0.1:80`. Please check that the NodeJs app and the DB are on the same host and on which Port the DB is listening on.

Comment: Server provider gaves me host as localhost